# Viewing javascript variable from any browser

Tags: javascript, html, session, cookies

I have variable in Javascript which are created by reading a number from HTML, adding a number to it and then returning it to HTML.

I want to make it so that no matter what browser/what user you are, you are seeing the latest version of the variable. Currently, if I refresh the page then the number resets to `0` (the default value). I want it so that if I update the number to `1` when someone else views it from another browser they will also see `1` and not `0`.

I've seen that cookies are an option, however I thought cookies were client side only? So that would mean that only I would see the latest version of the variable.

I've seen that sessions are another option, are sessions server side? And would they do the job that I am after?

Is there another way of doing this I haven't considered?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sessions dont work cross browsers.

The session is local to the browser.

Comment: you would need to do this on the server side

Comment: @MonicaAcha You can always restore that session to a new browser upon login or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make it so that no matter what browser/what user you are, you are seeing the latest version of the variable.

You need to send your updates from the browser to a server, and then have that server relay your updates to all the other clients.  There are many choices for how to do this, with various tradeoffs and complexity.

One method is to simply take that number and send it to the server.  Then, on next page load, the server injects that new number into the page it outputs (or it serves it up via an API call, over AJAX, via the Fetch API, or server-sent events, WebSocket, etc.).  If you do this though, you will need to decide how to handle concurrency.  What will happen if two people load the page at the same time?

The general system you're describing is called [Operational Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation), and this is a rabbit hole you probably don't want to go down right now.  Just understand that there's no magic that synchronizes things across the planet perfectly and at the same time.  Your system has to account for inherent delays in some way.

> I've seen that cookies are an option, however I thought cookies were client side only?

Yes, cookies are client-side.  They're sent to the server with every request, but that's not a useful tool for you, aside from session identification.

> I've seen that sessions are another option, are sessions server side?

They can be, but you need to find a way to know what the user is between browsers.  Normally, a session ID is stored in cookies.

Comment: If I were to put my files on a SFTB client. Would it technically be online "all of the time"? So the html would always be displaying be latest version of the variable? Or does it not work like this? (Apologies if my terminology isn't correct, just trying to get my head around it.)

Comment: @JackU I don't know what an SFTB client is.